# How do I show a form when another form has been closed? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vba, visual-studio

I want to be able to re-show my form once it has been hidden and the other forms have been closed.

To do so I have tried

```
if Form2.Close() and Form3.Close() then
me.Show()
End If
```

Comment: If isn't an event, this doesn't wait for something to happen. Use the form close event and check if your other relevent forms are open or closed, you're also confusing methods and attributes

Comment: You can't just say `Form1.Close()`, you have to use Private Subs to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

Use _Terminate

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
UserForm2.show
End Sub
```

Should do what you are trying to achieve ;P